# Android search dialog doesn't appear

Tags: android, search, dialog

Hello i am frustrated with the search dialog like presented on 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

No search dialog is shown to me when i press the search button on my device. here is my simple manifest file:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".Main"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".Other" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Other">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
    </activity>
</application>
```

My res/xml/searchable.xml looks like this:

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:label="lol"
   android:hint="search" >
</searchable>
```

in Main.java onSearchRequested() is triggered but no search dialog appears.

am i missing something?

Comment: oh my god. this is f*ing stupid.

i had to use android:label="@string/xyz" instead of android:label="lol"

and no single word about this in the documentation. unbelievable

Comment: I had this exact same problem. Very strange.

Comment: You can do it easily. see the answer here : stackoverflow.com/a/44131089/3649347

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The android:label attribute is the only required attribute. **It points to a string resource, which should be the application name.** This label isn't actually visible to the user until you enable search suggestions for Quick Search Box. At that point, this label is visible in the list of Searchable items in the system Settings."

Answer (score 2):

To remove the question from not answered, copying the comment with the solution:

> oh my god. this is f*ing stupid. i had to use
>   android:label="@string/xyz" instead of android:label="lol" and no
>   single word about this in the documentation. unbelievable